# remove listener defined in function thats out of scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module that has to recording functions I want to add. My problem is that because this.audio.stdout has a listener set for another function, I can only remove the listener activated when the start function is called without screwing up other processes. Because the value of filename changes based on when the function was called I have to define the callback in scope of when that value was set. This works for beginning recording with start() but when I call stop(), which removes the listener, the program doesn't know what to do because the callback is out of scope. What would be the proper way to do this?

```
function Record(rx) {
    this.rx = rx;
    this.audio = spawn('audio_client');
}

Record.prototype.start = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.filename= new Date().getTime()+'_'+this.rx

    function record(data) {
        console.log(self.filename);
    }
    this.audio.stdout.on('data', record);
}

Record.prototype.stop = function () {
    this.audio.stdout.removeListener('data',record);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I didn't understand what you were asking at first.  I looked at this for a bit and this is the best I could come up with.  It's not ideal to create the record method for each instance in the constructor like this, but again, this is the best I could come up with.

```
function Record(rx) {
    this.rx = rx;
    this.audio = spawn('audio_client');

    var self = this;
    this.record = function (data) {
        console.log(self.filename);
    };
}

Record.prototype.start = function () {
    this.filename= new Date().getTime()+'_'+this.rx
    this.audio.stdout.on('data', this.record);
};

Record.prototype.stop = function () {
    this.audio.stdout.removeListener('data', this.record);
};
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Better still since you are specific to node, would be `this.record = this.record.bind(this);`.